# "Named Pipes Provider, error 40" when connecting to serverless SQL Pool via PowerBI Desktop

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, azure-synapse, powerbi-datasource

We are getting a "'Named Pipes Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to' SQL Server'" error when trying to connect to our serverless SQL Pool via PowerBI Desktop.

We have tried the following:

1. Cleared the connection permissions in PowerBI
2. Tried all three authentication methods
3. Double checked the name of the SQL server
4. Made sure we are able to connect to the server using Azure Data Studio.
5. Tried using the Azure Synapse Analytics workspace (Beta) connector, which works. However using this connector we only access the lake database tables and not the views in the serverless SQL pool which we are interested in (we get an error pertaining to null values which seems to be a bug in the beta stage of this connector).

Comment: Works fine for me, but I do get that error if I try to connect to a SQL endpoint that doesn't exist.  Make sure you enter just the server name, eg `yourworkspacename-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net`.

Comment: I am also able to connect with serverless SQL pool when I enter correct endpoints and got similar error when I enter the endpoints which doesn't exist. you can get this serverless endpoints directly from portal go to your **`synapse workspace resource >> overview >> here you can see Serverless SQL endpoint`** just copy and paste this endpoint in powerBI where it asks for server name.

Comment: Thanks for responding @DavidBrowne-Microsoft (and PratikLad). Well that's embarrassing. Just goes to show you really have to double check the simplest things every now and then. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Posting it as answer to help for other community members.**

> **I got similar error when I enter the endpoints which doesn't exist or wrong.**

[image]

You can get this serverless endpoints directly from portal go to your **`synapse workspace resource >> overview >> here you can see Serverless SQL endpoint`**

[image]

just copy and paste this endpoint in powerBI where it asks for server name.

[image]

Enter the correct credentials of database like `Username` and `Password`

[image]

***Connected successfully***

[image]

**Note My database does not contain any table that's why it is not showing any table**